# How many fingerprints can android store now?

Tags: android, sqlite, project, fingerprint

I am working on the project for attendance using an android device. so the device can be circulated among the class and student can use the fingerprint sensor to mark their attendance for the particular class.
    if i am able to store the fingerprint in the SQLite. give me some idea how can i achieve this problem.
Thank you.

Comment: As far as I know, you can't store fingerprints or use them like the way you intended. Those fingerprints are stored in a secure place by android and only can be used by asking the system to authenticate the user. Additionally, I believe you can only store the maximum of 5 fingerprints but correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: The number is going to be determined by the model, it isn't going to be a constant across all devices.  Also, depending on where you live this could very well be illegal-  storing biometrics of other people have all sorts of special laws.

Comment: Similar questions have been asked several times before. The Android fingerprint API does not provide a way to match a fingerprint authentication against a specific enrolled fingerprint. All you get to know is whether the authentication matched _any of_ the enrolled fingerprints.